# Bash for loop - can the commands in the loop be added to the shell's history?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history, for

On the bash terminal if I execute the following for loop:

```
 for i in {1..5}; do echo $i;  done
```

The `echo` commands are not added to the history of the current shell. Is it because the commands in for (in `do` section) are run in subshell? If so is there a way to run them in the current shell instead? Or is it not possible because it's "running" `for` at the time?

Edit: Given it takes the entire for loop as one single compound command, if I remove the for loop and write the individual commands in five lines shouldn't all five be added to history?

I did the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o history

    var=5
    echo $((var--)) 
    echo $((var--)) 
    echo $((var--)) 
    echo $((var--)) 
    echo $((var--))
```

and ran the script using `source`. Still in history it shows only one echo statement `echo $((var--))` 
 and not all five. On the other hand, if instead of five `echo $((var--))`
 I put five `echo 5`, `echo 4`, ... `echo 1` commands all five are added to history.

Why?

Comment: `for i in {1..5}; do history -s echo $i;  done`  see `help history`

Comment: great. doing this the echo commands are added to history but oddly they don't output on current shell (nothing echoes.. l

Comment: `history` has some more option. try `help history`

Comment: The individual `echo` commands are not added because the _command_ being run is the compound `for` loop command (which _is_ added to the history). It has nothing to do with subshells.

Comment: No need for a loop, `echo 1; echo 2;` in one line is a single command in history, too ...

Comment: thanks all for answers

Comment: @pLumo what if I put 5 separate echo lines in bash script and run it using source command. even then out of 5 echo lines it's showing only one in history. I'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: This is because you have `ignoredups` in `$HISTCONTROL`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Oh.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your script wouldn't save history to ~/.bash_history at all in the
first place unless you exported `$HISTFILE` before running it. As it
says in `man bash` this is because:

> If HISTFILE is unset, or if the history file is unwritable, the
>   history is not saved.

`HISTFILE` is not an environment variable, it's a shell variable and
therefore not available in scripts which are child processes.  And
even if you ran these commands

```
$    var=5
$    echo $((var--))
$    echo $((var--))
$    echo $((var--))
$    echo $((var--))
$    echo $((var--))
```

(note the whitespaces after the prompt) in an interactive session and
not a script they wouldn't be saved to ~/.bash_history in practice
neither because popular Linux distributions such as Ubuntu set
`HISTCONTROL` to `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth` (which is an alias for
`ignorespace` and `ignoredups`) to not save commands that start with
one or more whitespaces.  This is especially useful if you work on a
shared server with other users and you intentionally don't want to
save a given command to the history so that other people could see it,
for example because it contains your password or other sensitive
information.

But even if there were no whitespaces before the command:

```
$ var=5
$ echo $((var--))
$ echo $((var--))
$ echo $((var--))
$ echo $((var--))
$ echo $((var--))
```

you would most probably end up with only a single `echo $((var--))`
entry in ~/.bash_history because `HISTCONTROL` commonly contains
`ignoredups` or the aforementioned `ignoreboth`. All of this is
described under `HISTCONTROL` section in Bash manpage you can invoke
with `man bash` on your system.